# "Write Conflict" error appears in single user database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

Running MS Access 2010 front end under Citrix against SQL Server 2008R2 backend.

I've got a form that's been working for quite some time. The code behind one button has suddenly started generating a 'Write Conflict' error. It happened a few days ago, and after several hours pouring over the unchanged code (confirmed with an online text comparison tool), and having another programmer here look over it, my only solution was to grab the production version of the front end and start reapplying my changes.

It's been running great for 2 days, and now the error happened again. I was changing code, but on a different form. I need to go through the processes on this form in order to test the other form.

Here is the code that is generating the Write Conflict:

```vb
Private Sub btnStart_Click()

Dim AuditID As String
Dim UserStatus As String
Dim SubmitPeerRev As Boolean
Dim PRPercent As Single
Dim ExaminerAudits As Integer
Dim ReviewAudits As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim UserName As String
Dim SQLString As String

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    UserStatus = funUserLookup("Status", Raw:=True)
    'get the percentage/whole number
    'this is the percentage that should be submitted for review
    If IsNull(DLookup("ItemValue", "tblConfig", "Item = '" & UserStatus & "'")) Then
        Form_frmMenu.MsgBoxTimed ("Your user ID is not configured correctly within the     AP_Audit DB." & vbCrLf & _
            "You cannot start an audit." & vbCrLf & _
            "Please contact your manager to get it set correctly.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        PRPercent = CSng(DLookup("ItemValue", "tblConfig", "Item = '" & UserStatus & "'"))
    End If
    UserName = funUserLookup("Examiner")

    'get total audits done
    SQLString = "SELECT count(*) as A " & _
                "  FROM tblAuditAtt " & _
                " WHERE Examiner = '" & UserName & "'" & _
                "   AND month(aMonth) = " & Month(Now()) & _
                "   AND year(aMonth) = " & Year(Now())
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLString, dbOpenDynaset)
    ExaminerAudits = rs.Fields("[A]")

    'get peer-reviewed audits done
    SQLString = "SELECT count(*) as A " & _
                    "  FROM tblAuditAtt " & _
                    " WHERE TraineeExaminer = '" & UserName & "'" & _
                    "   AND Month(aMonth) = " & Month(Now()) & _
                    "   AND Year(aMonth) = " & Year(Now())
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLString, dbOpenDynaset)
    ReviewAudits = rs.Fields("[A]")
    Set rs = Nothing

    If DLookup("Started", "tblAuditAtt", "AttAudit_ID = " & Me.AttAudit_ID) Then
        Form_frmMenu.MsgBoxTimed "This audit was already started by someone else. Select a new one."
        Me.Requery
        Exit Sub
    End If
        'UserName = funUserLookup("Examiner")
        If ReviewAudits = 0 Then            'ensure 1 review - prevents divide by 0
            Me.TraineeExaminer = UserName
            Me.TraineeExaminer.Visible = True
            Me.TraineeExaminer.Top = 2280
            Me.Examiner.Visible = False
        ElseIf ExaminerAudits = 0 And PRPercent < 1 Then      'ensure 1 non-review if < 100% peer-review
            Me.Examiner = UserName
            Me.TraineeExaminer.Visible = False
            Me.Examiner.Visible = True
        ElseIf ExaminerAudits / (ExaminerAudits + ReviewAudits) > 0.99999999 - PRPercent Then
            'the tiny fraction is needed because 0 > 0 = false & 100% trainees would get a straight submit
            Me.TraineeExaminer = UserName
            Me.TraineeExaminer.Visible = True
            Me.TraineeExaminer.Top = 2280
            Me.Examiner.Visible = False
        Else
            Me.Examiner = UserName
            Me.TraineeExaminer.Visible = False
            Me.Examiner.Visible = True
        End If

    Me.StartDate = Format(Form_frmMenu.GetSQLTime, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Me.Started = True
    Me.Dirty = False
    Form_frmMenu.ExecSP "AUDIT_AttAuditStart", 120, False, "@AuditID", adInteger, Me.AttAudit_ID
    'this is failing, for reasons yet unknown, so only continue if it hasn't
    If Nz(DLookup("AttAudit_A", "tblAuditAtt_A", "AttAudit_ID = " & Me.AttAudit_ID), 0) > 0 Then
        Me.btnStartEnd.Enabled = True
        Me.btnStartEnd.SetFocus
        Me.btnStart.Enabled = False
        Me.frmAttAudit_A_Sub.Requery
        SetSubFormView  'now that we know what type of audit & have questions, set up the proper view
    Else
        Me.TraineeExaminer = ""
        Me.Examiner = ""
        Me.StartDate = ""
        Me.Started = False
        Me.Dirty = False
        SQLString = Form_frmMenu.LogError(0, "Audit did not start properly", "User Defined", "frmAttAudit_A.btnStart_Click", "Stored procedure failed to insert records")
    End If

    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    If Form_frmMenu.LogError(err.Number, err.Description, err.Source, "frmAttAudit_A.btnStart_Click", SQLString) = "Next" Then
        Resume Next
    Else
            Resume
        End If

    End Sub
```

Notes:

- I'm running this on our dev server and I'm the only one using these
  tables
- I added a timestamp column, and that didn't seem to make any
  difference
- I've move the `me.dirty = false` code to after each bound form field change and that doesn't help
- The only solution previously was to get the production code and reapply all my changes by hand.
- you can see that there's another another oddity that's causing an insert query to fail. I don't know if it's happened since changing to calling a stored procedure, but it was failing when there was a `docmd.runsql` statement
- I received a suggestion in another post to disable hooking in the Citrix environment, since that might be messing things up, but our IT people won't look into that.

Any other thoughts or suggestions on how to resolve this? I really don't have time to redo my work every couple of days when Access decides to puke.

Comment: **warning** your code might be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: At the moment, it's not even vulnerable to running! >:/ Thanks, I see your point. What did you do to color the code? I'm still learning my way around here...

Comment: Do you know exactly which line is throwing the error? If not, you can go to Tools->Options->General to `Break on All Errors`, regardless of error handling. That's an easy way to pretend you have no error handling and just stop the code right where the error occurs.

Comment: it's on the `me.dirty = false` line. As soon as I try to force the update, it errors. I need that in there, because in the production database, I have about 35 users picking items to process from a common pool - if I don't set the 'started' flag right away, the next person can end up picking up the same item to process, and that's not good.

Comment: While a Form's dirty property is writable, I don't think it should be used that way. Create your own blnDirty variable and use that instead. You can always run a check `If Me.Dirty = True Then blnDirty = True`.

Comment: Thanks, @HK1 - as I understand it, setting me.dirty = false forces the record to be saved, which is what I'm after here, and I know that the record is dirty, because I've set values on a couple of bound form fields.

Comment: Why not use DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord? I'm not saying it will fix your problem but is the standard way to save a record.

Comment: I've seen many comments indicating that dirty = false is more reliable than acCmdSaveRecord. I have no empiracle evidence to prove it, just a general consensus of posts I've seen. Funny thing, since posting this question, I haven't received the Write Conflict error once.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying sql server table has bit fields with null values, this may cause a write conflict error from access when linked through odbc to sql server.  It has to do with access first converting the null bit value to 0 and then trying to apply the changes you made and causing a write conflict.

In my case, I solved it by have new bit fields default to 0 and replacing null values with 0 on existing fields.